# created a form in a loop, when posted does not show values

Tags: php, forms, loops, post

I'm recalling query values which are settings alongside their parameters. this includes the ID, value and description. As the fetch is in a form of a array i used a loop to display the different variables (this way if there are more settings to put in it is easier to expand). The loop consists of a different form allowing you to edit the value of the parameter of that setting. When you submit, it does not post the value, but it posts the ID attached to the button. What can I do?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM metadata";
$db->DoQuery($query);
$num = $db->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

if (isset($_POST)){
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo $_POST['service_name'];
    echo "</pre>";

}

echo "<table id='mytable' style='width:100%'>";
echo "<tr>
        <th>Option</th>
        <th>Value</th>
        <th>Description</th>
     </tr>";
foreach ($num as $row) {
    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['rule'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><input name="service_value" placeholder="value" value='.$row['value'].'></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['description'].'</td>';
    echo '<td><button value="'.$row[0].'" name="service_id"></button></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    }
?>
</form>
</table>
```

Comment: Start with closing each `<form>`.

Comment: The name of your input is service_value, but you're trying to echo out service_name.

Comment: You are creating fields in a loop, but using the same name - you will end up with multiple inputs named "service_value"  If that's your intent you should name the field service_value[] to get an array from $_POST